# JPA Collection Using Map

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

So I have a small proof of concept using JPA, Hibernate and Spring Data.  In this POC I have created a `Post` entity and a `Comment` entity.  The `Post` entity contains a map of comments `Map<Integer,Comment>`.

I was having issues persisting multiple `Comment` entities into the `Map` since I used the `Comment` entities `@Id` column as the key for the map.  Basically, if I didn't explicitly set the id of the `Comment` Hibernate recognized them as the same entity and only persisted one of them.

I found I could persist the `Map` by specifying garbage keys, which MySql autonumber would replace once persisted.  This led to an issue, the keys within the current map would not receive the new `commentId` values set by the database.  This caused my unit test to fail.

So basically I have three questions?

1. Should I specify garbage keys to persist the entities in the map?
2. Is my approach all wrong?  If so, whats a better way?
3. If garbage keys are ok, how can I refresh them after insert?

**Post.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "POST")
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "POST_ID")
    private Integer postId;

    @Column(name = "TITLE")
    private String title;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @MapKeyColumn(name="COMMENT_ID")
    private Map<Integer, Comment> comments = new HashMap<Integer, Comment>();

        /** Accessors (Get/Set) **/
        /** HashCode & Equals that does not consider the postId field or the Map */
}
```

**Comment.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="COMMENT")
public class Comment {

    @Id
    @Column(name="COMMENT_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer commentId;

    @Column(name="BODY")
    private String body;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="POST_ID")
    private Post post;

        /** Accessors (Get/Set) **/
        /** HashCode & Equals that does not consider the commentId field or the Post */
}
```

**Unit Test**

```
@Test
public void insertTest2(){
    Comment comment = new Comment();
    Comment comment2 = new Comment();
    final String body1 = "This is a map test";
    final String body2 = "This is another map test";

    comment.setBody(body1);
    comment2.setBody(body2);

    Post post = new Post();
    post.setPostDate(new Date());
    post.setTitle("First Post");


    post.getComments().put(1,comment);   //Setting garbage IDs
    post.getComments().put(2, comment2); //Setting garbage IDs

    comment.setPost(post);
    comment2.setPost(post);

    repository.save(post);

    Post dbpost = repository.findOne(post.getPostId());

    Map<Integer, Comment> comments = dbpost.getComments();

    //Test fails using old id       
    assertTrue(comments.containsKey(comment.getCommentId()));
    //Same here 
    assertTrue(comments.containsKey(comment2.getCommentId()));  

}
```

**Also note that this is a bidirectional relationship**

Comment: Why do you need a `Map`? Why not a simple `List` of Comments? since the key of the map is the id of the entity. Or is that what your POC is all about?

Comment: @RodrigoSasaki The whole point of my POC is to learn how to use a Map.  This is just for educational purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I specify garbage keys to persist the entities in the map?

No. As soon as the real ID would be affected, the map would be in an inconsistent state. Keys of a map should be immutable.

> Is my approach all wrong? If so, whats a better way?

Frankly, I don't really see the point in using a map to hold comments by ID. The entity manager is already able to get a comment by ID. I would simply use a Set or a List.

The alternative would be to persist the comments and flush the entity manager before adding them to the map, to make sure they already have a real ID.

Comment: This is just a POC, the whole point of it is to learn how to use a map.  I apologize I should have noted in the question about the approach that I didn't want to deviate from using a Map.  But your saying persist the comments then add them to map?  Ugghh, I was afraid of that.